# Ehcache Initial table allocation failed

Tags: java, ehcache

One of our web application runs within Tomcat 7 which is deployed on AS400 server, and it is using Ehcache as cache component swap data into disk and reduce memory usage.

Few weeks ago, when we try to deploy this application for one of our customer, it fails at startup. And log shows:

---

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cache 'data' creation in EhcacheManager failed.        
at org.ehcache.core.EhcacheManager.createCache(EhcacheManager.java:288)                           
at org.ehcache.core.EhcacheManager.init(EhcacheManager.java:567)                                                            
... 7 more                                                                                                                  
Caused by: org.ehcache.StateTransitionException: Initial table allocation failed.                                            
Initial Table Size (slots) : 64                                                                                              
Allocation Will Require    : 1KB                                                                                             
Table Page Source        : org.terracotta.offheapstore.disk.paging.MappedPageSource@bc8a4ca2                                 
at org.ehcache.core.StatusTransitioner$Transition.succeeded(StatusTransitioner.java:209)                                    
at org.ehcache.core.Ehcache.init(Ehcache.java:567)                                                                          
at org.ehcache.core.EhcacheManager.createCache(EhcacheManager.java:261)                                                     
... 8 more    
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Initial table allocation failed.                                              
Initial Table Size (slots) : 64                                                                                              
Allocation Will Require    : 1KB                                                                                             
Table Page Source        : org.terracotta.offheapstore.disk.paging.MappedPageSource@bc8a4ca2                                 
at org.terracotta.offheapstore.OffHeapHashMap.<init>(OffHeapHashMap.java:219)                                               
at org.terracotta.offheapstore.AbstractLockedOffHeapHashMap.<init>(AbstractLockedOffHeapHashMap.java:71)                    
at org.terracotta.offheapstore.AbstractOffHeapClockCache.<init>(AbstractOffHeapClockCache.java:76)                          
at org.terracotta.offheapstore.disk.persistent.AbstractPersistentOffHeapCache.<init>(AbstractPersistentOffHeapCache.java:43)
at org.terracotta.offheapstore.disk.persistent.PersistentReadWriteLockedOffHeapClockCache.<init>(PersistentReadWriteLockedOffHeapClockCache.java:36)
at org.ehcache.impl.internal.store.disk.factories.EhcachePersistentSegmentFactory$EhcachePersistentSegment.<init>(EhcachePersistentSegmentFactory.java:73)
at org.ehcache.impl.internal.store.disk.factories.EhcachePersistentSegmentFactory.newInstance(EhcachePersistentSegmentFactory.java:60)
at org.ehcache.impl.internal.store.disk.factories.EhcachePersistentSegmentFactory.newInstance(EhcachePersistentSegmentFactory.java:37)
at org.terracotta.offheapstore.concurrent.AbstractConcurrentOffHeapMap.<init>(AbstractConcurrentOffHeapMap.java:106)               
at org.terracotta.offheapstore.concurrent.AbstractConcurrentOffHeapCache.<init>(AbstractConcurrentOffHeapCache.java:48)            
at org.terracotta.offheapstore.disk.persistent.AbstractPersistentConcurrentOffHeapCache.<init>(AbstractPersistentConcurrentOffHeapCache.java:52) 
at org.ehcache.impl.internal.store.disk.EhcachePersistentConcurrentOffHeapClockCache.<init>(EhcachePersistentConcurrentOffHeapClockCache.java:52)
at org.ehcache.impl.internal.store.disk.OffHeapDiskStore.createBackingMap(OffHeapDiskStore.java:279)                               
at org.ehcache.impl.internal.store.disk.OffHeapDiskStore.getBackingMap(OffHeapDiskStore.java:167)                                  
at org.ehcache.impl.internal.store.disk.OffHeapDiskStore.access$600(OffHeapDiskStore.java:95)                                      
at org.ehcache.impl.internal.store.disk.OffHeapDiskStore$Provider.init(OffHeapDiskStore.java:460)                                  
at org.ehcache.impl.internal.store.disk.OffHeapDiskStore$Provider.initStore(OffHeapDiskStore.java:456)                             
at org.ehcache.impl.internal.store.disk.OffHeapDiskStore$Provider.initAuthoritativeTier(OffHeapDiskStore.java:507)                 
at org.ehcache.impl.internal.store.tiering.TieredStore$Provider.initStore(TieredStore.java:472)                                    
at org.ehcache.core.EhcacheManager$8.init(EhcacheManager.java:499)                                                                 
at org.ehcache.core.StatusTransitioner.runInitHooks(StatusTransitioner.java:135)                                                   
at org.ehcache.core.StatusTransitioner.access$000(StatusTransitioner.java:33)                                                      
at org.ehcache.core.StatusTransitioner$Transition.succeeded(StatusTransitioner.java:194)
```

---

this code triggered this is:

```
CacheConfiguration<String, String[]> dconf = CacheConfigurationBuilder
      .newCacheConfigurationBuilder(String.class, String[].class, ResourcePoolsBuilder.heap(11) 
      .disk(3, MemoryUnit.GB, false))
      .withExpiry(Expirations.timeToLiveExpiration(Duration.of(30, TimeUnit.MINUTES)))
      .build();
dataCacheManager = CacheManagerBuilder.newCacheManagerBuilder()
      .with(CacheManagerBuilder.persistence(new File(cacheFolder, "requestdata"))) //$NON-NLS-1$
      .withCache(CACHE_NAME_DATA,dconf)
      .build(true);
```

which surprised us because it has never happened before, we have deployed it for some other customers' server (Windows, As400, linux), none of them has this issues.

This is really a headache, we spend weeks try to figure it out, read source code, tuning jvm parameters, googling around..., nothing except one unanswered post: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ehcache-users/ApFAe5nYxuA

Is there anyone can help us one this? thanks ahead!

Comment: Are there no more "caused by" sections in the exception stack trace?

Comment: I am afraid there is no more caused by. that is why reading ehcache source code did not give us any thing.

Comment: just updated the exception trace, and put more to it.

Comment: When asking on SO always include the ENTIRE COMPLETE stack trace even if you don't think part of it is relevant.  It's ALL potentially relevant.  Question: Are any of your disks 100% full?  How about memory? Do you have a lot of free memory?

Comment: Disk is definitely not 100% full. and server has 32G memory in total, and we gave JVM 3G by using -xmx.  Memory should not be the reason, because according to tomcat manager, there are still more than 2 G free heap.

Answer (score 1):

The Ehcache 3 disk store uses `java.nio.MappedByteBuffer` which require access to direct memory.

There is no documented default `MaxDirectMemorySize` in Java and the same JVM on different OS can behave differently.

If you have not already set the flag `-XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=3G` when launching your application, it could be the cause of that exception you see.

Comment: Thanks very much, this indeed a possibility, I will try to add this parameter and see how it goes.

Comment: Did you find any solution? @XingweiWu